# Where can I see the Internet Explorer 8 console?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've read that Internet Explorer 8 has a console. I can't find it, even in Developer Tools. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in developer tools ( press <kbd>F12</kbd> ). You have to navigate to the **Script** tab.

[image]